# Web Scraping to extract options from MCQ's

Tags: jquery, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I'am trying to scrap http://www.geekmcq.com/verbal-ability/analogies/
to extract options from MCQ's. I'am doing this to get print of the questions the website is not print friendly. I have extracted the question and answers using nodejs with jquery style plugin `cheerio` but problem is with extraction of options. How can I extract them using jquery? I will use that syntax with nodejs pluging cheerio.

Here is screenshot of single mcq

[image]

HTML for single mcq as given in above screenshot

```
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td class="bix-td-qno" rowspan="2" align="left" valign="top">1.&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="bix-td-qtxt" valign="top">BIRD : NEST</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="bix-td-miscell" valign="top">
        <table class="bix-tbl-options" id="tblOption_3530" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="bix-td-option" id="tdOptionNo_A_3530" width="1%"><a id="lnkOptionLink_A_3530" href="javascript: void 0;">A.</a></td>
                    <td class="bix-td-option" id="tdOptionDt_A_3530" width="49%">horse : farm</td>
                    <td class="bix-td-option" id="tdOptionNo_B_3530" width="1%"><a id="lnkOptionLink_B_3530" href="javascript: void 0;">B.</a></td>
                    <td class="bix-td-option" id="tdOptionDt_B_3530" width="49%">squirrel : tree</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="bix-td-option" id="tdOptionNo_C_3530" width="1%"><a id="lnkOptionLink_C_3530" href="javascript: void 0;">C.</a></td>
                    <td class="bix-td-option" id="tdOptionDt_C_3530" width="49%">beaver : dam</td>
                    <td class="bix-td-option" id="tdOptionNo_D_3530" width="1%"><a id="lnkOptionLink_D_3530" href="javascript: void 0;">D.</a></td>
                    <td class="bix-td-option" id="tdOptionDt_D_3530" width="49%">cat : kitchen</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="bix-td-option" id="tdOptionNo_E_3530" width="1%"><a id="lnkOptionLink_E_3530" href="javascript: void 0;">E.</a></td>
                    <td class="bix-td-option" id="tdOptionDt_E_3530" width="49%">book : library</td>
                    <td class="bix-td-option" id="tdOptionNo_D_3530" width="1%"><strong class="ib-gray">&nbsp;</strong> <a id="lnkOptionLink_D_3530" href="javascript: void 0;"></a> </td>
                    <td class="bix-td-option" id="tdOptionDt_D_3530" width="49%">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <input class="jq-hdnakq" id="hdnAnswer_3530" value="C" type="hidden">
        <div class="bix-div-answer" style="display:none" id="divAnswer_3530">
            <div class="title-bar"><a href="javascript: void 0;" onclick="$('#divAnswer_3530').slideToggle('slow');">Answer &amp; Explanation</a></div>
            <div class="div-spacer">
                <p><span class="ib-green"><strong>Answer:</strong></span> Option <strong class="jq-hdnakqb">C</strong></p>
                <p><span class="ib-green"><strong>Explanation:</strong></span></p>
                <p> Bird makes nest as beaver makes dam. </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bix-div-workspace" style="display:none" id="divWorkspace_3530">
            <div class="title-bar"><a href="javascript: void 0;" onclick="$('#divWorkspace_3530').slideToggle('slow');">Workspace</a></div>
            <div class="div-spacer">
                <div class="div-calc" align="right">
                    <input value="Calc" size="15" class="calc-box hasCalculator" type="text"><img class="calculator-trigger" title="Open the calculator" alt="Open the calculator" src="http://www.geekmcq.com/images/calculator.png">
                </div>
                <textarea rows="10" cols="65" style="width:100%; padding: 10px;"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bix-div-report" style="display:none" id="divReport_3530">
            <div class="title-bar"><a href="javascript: void 0;" onclick="$('#divReport_3530').slideToggle('slow');">Report Errors</a></div>
            <div class="div-spacer"> 
                <textarea onchange="javascript:if(this.name == '')this.name='txtReport_3530';" name="" id="txtReport_3530" rows="8" cols="65" style="width:100%;padding:10px;">Kindly mention the details of the error here...
                [Your Name]
                [Your Email]</textarea> 
                <input id="btnReport_3530" onclick="SendBixReport('1', '3530')" value="Send Report" style="margin-top:2px" type="button">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bix-div-toolbar" id="divToolBar_3530">
            <a class="answer" href="javascript: void 0;" onclick="$('#divAnswer_3530').slideToggle('slow')">View Answer</a>
            <a class="workspace" href="javascript: void 0;" onclick="$('#divWorkspace_3530').slideToggle('slow')">Workspace</a>
            <a class="report" href="javascript: void 0;" onclick="$('#divReport_3530').slideToggle('slow')">Report</a>  
            <a class="discuss" href="http://www.geekmcq.com/verbal-ability/analogies/discussion-3530">Discuss in Forum</a>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take this code man (:

```
var
  cheerio = require('cheerio'),
  request = require('request');

function getHTML(url, callback) {
  request.get(url, function(err, response, body) {
    if(err) {
      console.error(err);
      return callback();
    }

    callback(body);
  });
}

var url = 'http://www.geekmcq.com/verbal-ability/analogies/';
getHTML(url, function(html) {
  var $ = cheerio.load(html);
  var questions = [];
  $('#ib-main-bar .bix-div-container').each(function() {
    var question = {
      text: $(this).find('table:nth-child(1)>tr:nth-child(1)>td:nth-child(2)').html(),
      options: {},
      answer: null
    };

    var $optionsPart = $(this).find('table:nth-child(1)>tr:nth-child(2)');
    question.options.A = $optionsPart.find('tr:nth-child(1)>td:nth-child(2)').html();
    question.options.B = $optionsPart.find('tr:nth-child(1)>td:nth-child(4)').html();
    question.options.C = $optionsPart.find('tr:nth-child(2)>td:nth-child(2)').html();
    question.options.D = $optionsPart.find('tr:nth-child(2)>td:nth-child(4)').html();
    question.options.E = $optionsPart.find('tr:nth-child(3)>td:nth-child(2)').html();
    question.answer = $optionsPart.find('.jq-hdnakq').val();

    questions.push(question);
  });

  console.log(questions);
});
```

It returns array of objects with attributes: `text, options, answer`

screenshot: http://joxi.ru/a2X77bSy3975mg